# How to call method inside of usercontrol which is nested inside of RadDockableObject from content page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

Here is my code. I'm able to find Asp.net UserControl and play with attributes but I need to call specific method inside of it. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

```
var usercontrol = (UserControl)RadDockableObject1.FindControl("ControlName");
usercontrol.Visible = true;
usercontrol.MethodName();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast it to the appropriate type.  Right now you are casting it to UserControl.  That will give you access to a set of properties and methods, but not all.  Cast it to the particular type and you will have access to everything.  Everything that is not-private that is...

Comment: @Eugene, look at LukaszW.pl's answer.

Comment: Do I need to cast based on UserControl ID?

Answer (score 1):

Just cast it to your control type instead of UserControl f.e.

```
var myControl = (SpecificControlName)RadDockableObject1.FindControl("ControlName");
myControl.SpecificMethod();
```

Comment: I was 21 seconds too slow...  ;-)

Comment: Is it should be UserControl ID?

Comment: If you are asking about SpecificControlName then its name of a class. Your control has code behind, there is a class.. This is it's name. If it helps, please mark answer :)